# SQL - Select where current months falls within a range

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying expand my (Oracle) SQL skills and I recently came across this situation and I figured it would be a good example to learn from. I could handle this easily with Python but I would like give it a try in SQL.

I have a application that needs to query a different product depending on the current month. I am having trouble writing the correct sql to get the winter product since the month range crosses the new year, and the basic `WHERE` statements with greater than and less then will not be enough.

```
Product  Start_Month  End_Month  
------   -----------  ---------  
Shorts        5           9  
Jackets      10           4
```

I have been tinkering with some CASE WHEN statements but I haven't got anything worth showing. The below SQL works fine on the summer season, but fails for the winter. It obviously needs some conditional statements, and I have not found any good advanced SQL tutorials with examples. Any advice on how to improve the following SQL to return the correct row?

```
SELECT Product FROM SEASONAL_PRODUCTS 
WHERE Start_Month <= extract(month from sysdate) 
AND End_Month > extract(month from sysdate);
```

Comment: And in your data for Jackets you have start_month greater than end_month so if this is valid data it needs to be taken care of in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use a double condition because range are different

```
WHERE  
(     Start_Month < End_Month  
  AND Start_Month <= extract(month from sysdate) AND End_Month >= extract(month from sysdate)
)            
OR   
(     Start_Month > End_Month  
  AND (Start_Month <= extract(month from sysdate) OR End_Month >= extract(month from sysdate)  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: I think I have it. Need double check when need `>` or `>=`

Comment: Still in issue in say, Feb. But I think we can get there by adding another set of where conditions to test if its the beginning or end of the year.

Comment: I just update the code.. first case you need `AND`  for `start, end` for second case you need `OR` for each one.

Comment: Let say today is `14-feb` month will be 4. Then for shorts `start 5 <= 4` will be false. For Jackets  `END 4 >= 4` so true on the `OR` part

Comment: lol , I just realize a mistake, I mean `14-april -> month = 4`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't have ranges of months that are over a year, you could try something like the below code:

```
SELECT Product
FROM SEASONAL_PRODUCTS 
WHERE sysdate BETWEEN to_date(start_month  || '-'  || extract(YEAR FROM sysdate), 'MM-YY')
AND
  CASE
    WHEN END_MONTH - START_MONTH <= 0
    THEN to_date(end_month  || '-'  || (extract(YEAR FROM sysdate) + 1), 'MM-YY')
    ELSE to_date(end_month  || '-'  || (extract(YEAR FROM sysdate)), 'MM-YY')
  END;
```

It is a bit messy but its an alternate solution to Juan Carlos Oropeza's answer.

Comment: Took me a while to understand your answer. I think if you use better indentation and `START_MONTH >= END_MONTH` Would be easier to read